# Почему 1 id перекрывает 11 классов?

Tags: html, css

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
    
            #id {
                color: red;
            }
        
            .q.w.e.r.t.y.u.i.o.p.a{
                color: green;
            }
        
        
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="q w e r t y u i o p a" id="id">bla bla</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Можно использовать `green !important`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

CSS-селекторы имеют свой вес, который определяет как взаимодействуют одинаковые свойства, заданные в разных местах кода одному и тому же элементу.

Вес селекторов:

```
style=""     — 1,0,0,0
#id          — 0,1,0,0
.class       — 0,0,1,0
[attr=value] — 0,0,1,0
LI           — 0,0,0,1
*            — 0,0,0,0
```

Примеры:

```
LI              — 0,0,0,1 — селектор по тегу
UL LI           — 0,0,0,2 — селектор c двумя тегами весит больше, чем с одним.
.orange         — 0,0,1,0 — селектор с классом весит больше, чем селектор с тегом.
.orange A SPAN  — 0,0,1,2 — селектор перевесит предыдущий, потому что помимо класса содержит два тега.
#page .orange   — 0,1,1,0 — селектор с ID перевесит всё, кроме inline-стилей.
```

Есть еще **!important**, которым можно перебить даже inline стиль. Но обычно это нужно в крайних случаях. Если н используется часто, значит что-то сделано не так.

---

В целом, если у вас будет даже 156 классов подряд, то вес будет

```
0 0 156 0
```

что все равно никогда не побьет айдишник

---

P.S. Если интересно, можете поэкспериментировать с **[онлайн калькулятором весов селекторов](https://specificity.keegan.st/)**

Answer (score 1):

В CSS, наиболее приоритетным селектором является `id` и он всегда перекрывает стили для классов или для тегов